# How to run a Google App Engine cron job in in every weekday?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

The complete description would be:

run a `cron` job in every 15 minutes, from 8:00 am to 5:00pm, every weekday (MON-FRI) pacific time. Also it would be better to be adjustable to daylight saving changes

How to do it in a cron.yaml in GAE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Cron gives you one of two formats, but not both:

```
every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
```

or

```
("every"|ordinal) (days) ["of" (monthspec)] (time)
```

Your best workaround would be to use:

```
every 15 minutes from 8:00 to 17:00
```

and then in code filter out weekends.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, you can create a new cron job for each day of the week! E.g., 
every monday ...
every tuesday ...
every wednesday ...

and of course skip the weekends.

Comment: I think this is still subject to the same limit because there's no way to specify from 8:00am - 5:00pm if you also specify the day of the week